# Laravel 4 Unique values

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

i'm using latest version of `laravel` framework and i want to set `unique` fields to validator class such as email.

this below rule dont work correctly.

My Rule:

```
$rules = array(
            'name'       => 'required',
            'email'      => 'required|email|unique:email',
            'nerd_level' => 'required|numeric'
);
```

i want to have unique email to register users.

Comment: What is happening when you try to validate?

Comment: And how are you going about the validation?

Comment: @Ir1sh. i want to forbidden to user can register duplicate email address.email must be unique in database and to register form

Comment: I understand, but what error are you getting when you try to validate the input if any and can you post the code that is validating the input?

Comment: @Ir1sh, `SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'laravel.email' doesn't exist (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from email where email = test@test.com) `

Comment: what is the name of your users table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first field after unique: should be the table name and the second field should be the column name if you want to specify it, if you dont specify it then the input filed name is used. http://laravel.com/docs/validation#rule-unique

Try this where Users is the name of the table you are storing your users in

```
$rules = array(
            'name'       => 'required',
            'email'      => 'required|email|unique:Users',
            'nerd_level' => 'required|numeric'
);
```

if you want to specify the email field use this

```
$rules = array(
                'name'       => 'required',
                'email'      => 'required|email|unique:Users,email',
                'nerd_level' => 'required|numeric'
    );
```

Comment: thanks. i get this error now.`
SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'laravel.Users' doesn't exist (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from Users where  email = test@test.com)`

Comment: What is the name of the table you are saving your users in?

Comment: if it is called users then try without the caps, if it is not called users enter whatever it is called

Comment: my database is laravel and table of that is nerds

Comment: then use nerds where I have users

Comment: i'm using this tutorila: http://scotch.io/tutorials/simple-laravel-crud-with-resource-controllers. get error:`SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column ' email' in 'where clause' (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from nerds where email = kjlk@jkljlk.com) `

Comment: delete the space in front of email from required|email|unique:Users, email so that its required|email|unique:Users,email

Comment: @Ir1sh.Moving the discussion to chat failed. do not resolve problem :(

Comment: What happens when you use this rule exactly as it is typed now 'required|email|unique:nerds,email'